# Syntax errors and why am I getting them?

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing a problem for my Java class that involves getting the total amount, average amount, least amount, and the most amount of rain for a year. I for the life of me cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am getting syntax errors and I do not quite understand why.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rainfall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int ttlMonth = 12; // for total months , which will always be 12//
        double[] mRain = new double[ttlMonth]; //mRain for monthly rain//
        int i = 0; //for use in the array//
        double ttlRain; //total rain//
        double avgRain; //average rain//
        double maxRain; //most rain//
        double minRain; //least rain//

        System.out.println("Enter the monthly rain fall amount: ");


        for(i = 0; i < ttlMonth; i++){

            do{
                System.out.print("Month " + (i+1) + ": ");
                mRain[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
            }
            while(mRain[i] < 0);            
        }
            //tTl for total//
            ttlRain(double[] array) {
                double tTl = 0; 
                for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    tTl += array[i];
                    } 
                ttlRain = tTl; 
                }
            //aVg for average//
            avgRain(double[] array) {
                double aVg = 0; 
                aVg = ttlRain(array)/array.length;
            }

            //mAx for the most rainfall//
            maxRain(double[] array) {
                double mAx = 0; 
                for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    if(array[i] > mAx){
                        mAx = array[i];
                    }
                }

            }           
            //mIn for the least amount of rainfall//
            minRain(double[] array) {
                double mIn = array[0]; 
                for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    if(array[i] < mIn){
                        mIn = array[i];
                    }
                }

            }
        System.out.println("The yearly sum of rain: " + ttlRain);
        System.out.println("The average ammount of rain: " + avgRain);
        System.out.println("The most amount of rain fall: " + maxRain);
        System.out.println("The least amount of rain fall: " + minRain);
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the error that you are getting?

Comment: Where does the syntax error occur? Please provide more details

Comment: You are trying to put methods inside methods, that'll never work. You should [study the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Comment: the syntax errors themselves are an indication of what you did wrong and where, have you read them?

Comment: I suspect that this question could be closed as typo/unrepro, or maybe lacking an [mcve]. Pleased you solved it though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here. Why don't you read more about Java:

1. Java method declaration syntax is wrong it's as below

   ```
   [public|private|protected|default] [void|return_type] methodname([parameters...])
   ```

   e.g.  `private void ttlRain(double[] array) {`
2. In Java a method is not directly declared inside another method. Hence move out your methods outside main method. And either make those static or call by creating object of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues with Java language:

1. Because you are executing a static function, all functions called inside need to be static too

Example, given:

```
 static void a(){
    b(); // does not compile
    c(); // compiles
 }

 void b(){}
 static void c(){}
```

2. All functions need to have declared a return type, like void or a double (in your case)
3. All functions that return something, need a return keyword, with returned value.
4. You cannot create a named function inside of another function, you can create an annonymous lambda function though

Example, given:

```
    double avgRain(double[] array) { // declares a double return type
        return 9.0;
    }
    void print(double in) { // does not return anything. This is a voif function
        System.out.println(in)
    }
```

5. In order to call a function, you need to pass all required arguments

Example:

```
  double sum(double a,double  b){
    return a+b;
  }
  sum(); // does not compile
  sum(1.0,4.0); // compiles
```

After applying above changes to your code, it compiles and works

```
public class Rainfall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int ttlMonth = 12; // for total months , which will always be 12//
        double[] mRain = new double[ttlMonth]; //mRain for monthly rain//

        System.out.println("Enter the monthly rain fall amount: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < ttlMonth; i++) {

            do {
                System.out.print("Month " + (i + 1) + ": ");
                mRain[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
            }
            while (mRain[i] < 0);
        }

        System.out.println("The yearly sum of rain: " + ttlRain(mRain));//5
        System.out.println("The average amount of rain: " + avgRain(mRain));//5
        System.out.println("The most amount of rain fall: " + maxRain(mRain));//5
        System.out.println("The least amount of rain fall: " + minRain(mRain));//5
    }

    //tTl for total//
    private static double ttlRain(double[] array) { // 1,2,3
        double tTl = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            tTl += array[i];
        }
        return tTl;//4
    }

    //aVg for average//
    private static double avgRain(double[] array) { // 1,2,3
        return ttlRain(array) / array.length;
    }

    //mAx for the most rainfall//
    private static double maxRain(double[] array) { // 1,2,3
        double mAx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > mAx) {
                mAx = array[i];
            }
        }
        return mAx;
    }

    //mIn for the least amount of rainfall//
    private static double minRain(double[] array) { // 1,2,3
        double mIn = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < mIn) {
                mIn = array[i];
            }
        }
        return mIn;
    }
}
```